# How does AWS Route 53 weighted routing policy record TTL affect clients after expiration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Say I'm testing a new version of my application and I create a weighted routing policy for my domain that sends 25% of users to the new version and the remaining users to the old version.

A user arrives and they are sent to the new version. However, TTL is set low to something like "60" seconds. After the DNS record expires their client is going to query again.

Is Route 53 smart enough to send them to the new version again or will it be random and they only have a 25% chance to be sent to the same version?

My assumption is that it will be the latter and left to chance which would align with what I'm seeing. However, I haven't seen any articles or resources that answer this specific question.

Comment: It's the latter. I can't find a cite, but Route 53's records are definitely not sticky on a user level.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz. Sticky is a good description of that. This was the first time I played with the Route 53 traffic flow policies. It worked for the most part but some errors seemed to be caused by the above. Something to keep in mind when doing blue/green deployments.

Comment: Yeah, at the load balancer level, we'd call it "sticky sessions". AWS's load balancers have that, but that's on a regional level, not global.